# How to resolve Pandas Read csv not working for Mock S3?

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, mocking, moto

I created a mock s3 bucket with moto. I put an object into it. I am trying to read with pandas read_csv.

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME = 'mock_bucket'
def s3_bucket():
    mocks3 = mock_s3()
    mocks3.start()
    os.environ["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"] = "us-east-1"
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.create_bucket(Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME)
    return s3
s3 = s3_bucket()
bucket = s3.Bucket(S3_BUCKET_NAME)

bucket.put_object(Key='/2022/12/14/6/25/t_ext_gop/t.csv', Body='test')
a = pd.read_csv('s3://amx-mock-bigdata-stemtime/2022/12/14/6/25/t_ext_gop/t.csv')
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'MockRawResponse' object has no attribute 'raw_headers'
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Do you use aio-botocore? That is a known issue with that lib, see https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore/issues/755

Comment: Did you find a solution how to unittest using read_csv and moto?